# How to add text after # but not #?

Tags: javascript, text, meteor, tags

This is the code that I am currently using to put tags in text into a array `hashtags` that is put into a mongodb collection. It currently puts every bit of text that starts with # into the array `hashtags`. Thanks to [@saimeunt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2530970/saimeunt)'s help; but I need to not include the # in the hashtags array just the text after it. Thanks in advanced.

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var posttext=$(e.target).find('[name=posttext]').val();
    var hashtags=posttext.match(/#\w+/g);

var post = {
  title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
  posttext:posttext,
  hashtags:hashtags
}
```

Comment: This seems like maybe it's a follow-up to a previous question or something, I'm not sure... but it's somewhat missing context. Can you explain clearly what you're doing here and what's going wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var myString = "#123abc #gg #d";
var myRegexp = /#(\w+)/g;
match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
var matched = [];
while (match != null) {
  // capturing group n: match[n]    
  matched.push(match[1])

  match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
alert(matched)
```